# moving imageview at top

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

I have an image of size 519px X 420px that I want to place at the top of my android screen. Now there is some empty white space between my image and the header that I want to remove at all.

XML code:

```
<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image: Preview]

Please see above screenshot and help me update my XML in such a way so that empty space between blue header and the image get completely vanished.

Thanks in advance!

Complete XML code as requested:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.sitemakers.sitemakers.AboutFragment">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your complete xml file

Comment: Yes complete xml code added in question now. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)**

> Options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this view.
>
> Use   **`android:scaleType="fitXY"`**
>
> Scale the image using FILL.

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="420dp" />
```

Comment: Yes white space removed but image stretches. Its height increases.

Comment: try with static height only of you aware of image height

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)**

> Options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this view.

use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
    <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated XML code for posting image just after header. We have to give static height of the image along with android `scaleType`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="in.sitemakers.sitemakers.AboutFragment">

    <ImageView
       android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:layout_height="420dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain..? why you are giving ans to your own question while other user gives the right ans

Comment: Delete this answer. if you got solution then it's good but didn't post answer in your own question. @nilesh right buddy.

Comment: Yes my dear friends, I can explain. nilesh partly given the right answer and pritesh given the remaining one. By using both my friends answers, I can able to join both and finds the solutions, so that's why posted the final answer. Clear my friends :)  Even I mark @nilesh answer as useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **android:scaleType="fitXY"**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```